# How to use non-default constructors with Ninject?

Tags: c#, ninject

How to use Ninject with a sample code for interface and its implementation like this:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    // common methods for all content types
    void Insert(BaseContentObject o);
    void Update(BaseContentObject o);
    void Delete(string slug);
    void Delete(ContentType contentType, string slug);
    IEnumerable<BaseContentObject> GetInstances();
    BaseContentObject GetInstance(ContentType contentType, string slug);
    BaseContentObject GetInstance(string contentType, string slug);
    BaseContentObject GetInstance(string slug);
    IEnumerable<string> GetSlugsForContentType(int limit = 0, string query = "");
    ContentList GetContentItems();
    bool IsUniqueSlug(string slug);
    string ObjectPersistanceFolder { get; set; }
}

public class XmlDefaultRepository : IRepository
{
    private ContentType SelectedType;

    public XmlDefaultRepository(string contentType)
    {
        SelectedType = (ContentType) Enum.Parse(typeof(ContentType), contentType);
    }

    public void Insert(Models.ContentClasses.BaseContentObject o)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // ...
}

public class PageController : BaseController
{
    private IRepository ContentRepository { get; private set; }

    public PageController(IRepository repository)
    {
        ContentRepository = repository;
    }

    // 
    // GET: /{slug}
    // GET: /Pages/{slug}
    public ActionResult Display(string slug)
    {
        // sample repository usage
        Page page = ContentRepository.GetInstance(slug);
        // ...
    }
}
```

My code does not contain default constructor because I don't need one (even if wanted to create it I couldn't because I always require the content type to be provided.

I cannot make a default constructor because there is logically no default content type to be provided.

This is the exception that Ninject produces when trying to load my ASP.NET MVC page.

*Error activating string

No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Activation path:

3. Injection of dependency string into parameter contentType of constructor of type XmlDefaultRepository
4. Injection of dependency IRepository into parameter repository of constructor of type PageController
5. Request for IController

Suggestions:

1. Ensure that you have defined a binding for string.
2. If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
3. Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
4. If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldnt need to introduce a default ctor just to please Ninject.

Assuming you're using V2, [the semantics for how a constructor is chosen are detailed here](http://kohari.org/2009/02/25/ninject-2-reaches-beta/)

(BTW By default, the `string` type is not treated as a resolvable type OOTB, but you should be able to `Bind` `ContentType` `To` something and have that constructor invoked).

If none of the above gets you moving, can you please supply a usage scenario and/or an exception detailing the issue you're having.

EDIT: It's not clear to me at this point that you're definitely in a situation where you shouldnt be adding a `ConstructorArgument` ((probably via `WithConstructorArgument()` IIRC) to your `Bind<T>()` statement.

Comment: I've updated my code and provided the exception from Ninject.

Comment: If I continue on the above code and do this in my Ninject Module
Bind<IRepository>().To<XmlDefaultRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("contentType", "Page");
then it works, however the thing is, I cannot bind my contentType constructor parameter just to "Page" in my Module. This constructor parameter is controller dependant. So in my PageController,  XmlDefaultRepository would be instantiated with a "Page" value for contentType but in some other controller like a ServiceController, the "contentType" parameter value should equal to "Service".

Comment: Hopefully you understand I therefore cannot hardcode the value for "contentType" parameter in the Module. How can I solve this problem? What's the thing about controller factories etc.?

Comment: IIAC, you can use the .When and .Only etc. to say "when the context says that we're injecting into an X" - one can then put in spearate `Bind`ing registrations for each context. That route will work fine as long as everythign can be known at the time of controller instantiation. If it's only clear at the time the action gets invoked, then it needs to become a param. But I'm sure you figured that out. Huighly recommend looking at the Ninject unit tests to see examples of all the sorts of things you can do around this sort of thing.

Comment: Your suggestion to look at Ninject.Tests helped a lot though some methods like WhenClassHas are not being tested. But this was the method that, in conjunction with class attributes, worked for me.

Comment: @mare: Great stuff - It's mainly prodding like this from @Ian Davis that led me there (I used to use reflector on Ninject and disregard the tests). Now you have the baton of replying to Ninject questions on SO with USL comments and/or go to the mailign list :P